# Not able to call API data through Angular-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling data from my api using - my setup includes angularjs, so I am trying to call through a controller, but some of the data or events does not respond.

so here's my code:

```js
myApp.controller('someAppController',['$scope', '$http','$state','apiUrl','$q','$timeout','$interval', function ($scope, $http, $state,apiUrl,$q,$timeout,$interval) {
      var apiURL = apiUrl+"fetchData";
      $scope=this;        
      
   $scope.fetchAppData = function(device,os){
   $scope.dt = device; 
   $scope.platform = os;
   $scope.startDate = $('#sDate').val();
   $scope.endDate = $('#eDate').val();
    var startDate = $scope.startDate;
    var endDate = $scope.endDate;
    var deviceType = $scope.dt;
    var oSystem = $scope.platform;
    var appKey = localStorage.getItem("appKey");
    var i;
   var dfrd = $q.defer();
   $http.get(apiURL, 
    {
     params:{type: deviceType, platform : oSystem, sd: startDate, ed: endDate, akey: appKey},
   
      
    }
   )
   .then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
    var data = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
     var tts = data[i].tts;
     var ts = data[i].ts;
     var nuu = data[i].nuu;
     var atsps = data[i].tts / data[i].ts;
     var atsbu = data[i].tts / data[i].nuu;
     
     if ( isNaN(atsps)||  atsps == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || atsps == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || atsps === null)
      { //console.log("false atsps" +atsps);
       data[i].atsps = 0;
      }
     else{
      data[i].atsps = atsps; 
     }
     if ( isNaN(atsbu) || atsbu == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || atsbu == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || atsbu === null)
      {
       //console.log("false atsbu" +atsbu);
       data[i].atsbu = 0;
      } 
     else{ 
      
       data[i].atsbu = atsbu;
      }
    }
   $scope.users = data;
    
   }, function(x) {
    dfrd.reject(true);
   });
   return dfrd.promise;
   
  };
 $scope.cb= function(start, end){
    $('#dateRangescreenAnalytics span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    startDateCal = start;
    endDateCal = end;
    $scope.fetchAppData($scope.dt,$scope.platform);
}
  
 $scope.cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());
   

$('#dateRangescreenAnalytics').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
       'Last Week': [moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week'), moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week')],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
},
locale: {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    applyLabel: "Select"
 },
startDate: startDateCal,
endDate: endDateCal
}, $scope.cb);


}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="someAppController as deviceCtrl">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="page">
   <div class="row breadcrumb bg-white border-bottom paddl30">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Voices</a></li>
      <li> &gt; </li>
      <li>Datas</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row bg-white border-bottom">

     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="photos" autofocus>
       <img ng-repeat="user in deviceCtrl.users" class="cover" data-name="{{user.name}}" ng-src="{{user.path}}"/> 
  
      </div><!-- End of Photos -->
      <div id="photos-info">
       <div id="photos-name"></div>
      </div>
     </div> <!-- End of col md 12 -->

    </div><!-- End of row -->
    <div class="carousel-info text-right col-md-12">
      <p>Use arrow < > keys or mouse scroll to view carousel.</p>
     </div>
     
    <div class="row">
     <ul class="info-container" ng-repeat="user in users" style="display:none">
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Number of unique users</h3></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.nuu}}</p></div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>number of crashes</h3></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.noc}}</p></div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>total time spent</h3></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.tts |secondsToHHmmss}}</p></div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Average Time spent by user</h3></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.atsbu |secondsToHHmmss}}</p></div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Total sessions</h3></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.ts}}</p></div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
       <div class="info">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Average time spent per sessions</h3></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{ deviceCtrl.user.atsps |secondsToHHmmss}} </p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

so basically

*

```
<div class="row">
                    <ul class="info-container" ng-repeat="user in users" style="display:none">
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Number of unique users</h3></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.nuu}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>number of crashes</h3></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.noc}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>total time spent</h3></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.tts |secondsToHHmmss}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Average Time spent by user</h3></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.atsbu |secondsToHHmmss}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Total sessions</h3></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{deviceCtrl.user.ts}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>Average time spent per sessions</h3></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12"><p>{{ deviceCtrl.user.atsps |secondsToHHmmss}} </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

*

part of the code does not respond ?! While, it is supposed to show values. 
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling $scope.cb() function?

Comment: @Sarbanjeet - updated the code.

Comment: do you have angular.module ?

Comment: Yup, but that's just calling the required things when page loads - whats up with that ? @Grisza

Comment: what is structure of this JSON which you fetch? Do you have somewhere this file? Show the structure and maybe getting values incorrectly. Is this API free so I can see this file but I don't know where it is. Are the keys named tts, ts and nuu in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed to call your method. 
At the end of your controller add this:

```
$scope.fetchAppData();
```

Comment: actually I have called that too, forgot to add that part - it is updated now. but that does not help - Issue still exists.

Comment: is the controller correctly called? If you put a `console.log('init');` at the beginning of you controller, does it show up?

Comment: yup, it does gets called.

Comment: just tried your example, the code works fine. Are you sure that you have a main container where your app is set up?
`<body ng-app="myApp">...</body>`

Comment: code would work fine - with no error but my question is why some part of code is just not responding - I am new to angular dev

Comment: Can you change your http call in this way to see if you have some output please?
`$http(req).then(function(){ console.log('success'); }, function(){ console.log('failed'); });`
With req I mean your URL and your params of course, so change that according to your code